# How do I absolute center a responsive svg background?

Tags: css, svg, responsive

I'm trying to achieve the following result:
[image]

The body has a black background and a fixed height of the browser window. The graphic is a simple SVG with 50px margins on each side. This ratio should stay consistent as the browser resizes.

Comment: What "ratio" should stay consistent? Do you mean the 50px margin should maintain (showing 50px of black background all around) as the browser resizes?

Comment: Yes exactly! I would like the svg to be fluid width with a little black always appearing around the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the fixed-width black border as the stroke around the svg rectangle, which itself takes up the full width & height of the window. Something like this should do the trick for you (the snippit won't reder it properly so don't try running it in place--copy the code out to a separate file or to your page):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="bgGradient">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#fe7b47" />
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#8cbef7" />
 </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100vw" height="100vh" fill="url(#bgGradient)" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="100px" />
</svg>
```